# Difference pandas.DateTimeIndex without a frequency

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, data-science

An irregular time series `data` is stored in a `pandas.DataFrame`. A `DatetimeIndex` has been set. I need the time difference between consecutive entries in the index.

I thought it would be as simple as

```
data.index.diff()
```

but got

```
AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'diff'
```

I tried

```
data.index - data.index.shift(1)
```

but got

```
ValueError: Cannot shift with no freq
```

I do not want to infer or enforce a frequency first before doing this operation. There are large gaps in the time series that would be expanded to large runs of `nan`. The point is to find these gaps first.

So, what is a clean way to do this seemingly simple operation?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no implemented `diff` function yet for index.

However, it is possible to convert the index to a `Series` first by using [`Index.to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html), if you need to preserve the original index. Use the `Series` constructor with no index parameter if the default index is needed.

Code example:

```
rng = pd.to_datetime(['2015-01-10','2015-01-12','2015-01-13'])
data = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(3)}, index=rng)  
print(data)
             a
 2015-01-10  0
 2015-01-12  1
 2015-01-13  2

a = data.index.to_series().diff()
print(a)

2015-01-10      NaT
2015-01-12   2 days
2015-01-13   1 days
dtype: timedelta64[ns]

a = pd.Series(data.index).diff()
print(a)
 0      NaT
 1   2 days
 2   1 days
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: Nice solution. So an index is not automatically a series, need to remember that.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit old but anyway...

I use `numpy.diff(data.index)` to get the time deltas. Working fine.