# Colour fill on plot based on conditions with python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plotly

I have plotted a graph with dataset `df`, where `Timestamp` is the index:

`df`:

```
      Timestamp     Temperature     
2020-02-06 08:23:04 18.5    
2020-02-06 08:23:05 18.5    
2020-02-06 08:23:06 18.5    
2020-02-06 08:23:07 18.5    
2020-02-06 08:23:08 18.5    
... ... ...
2020-02-06 20:14:36 21.0
```

and code

```
df.plot( y='Temperature', figsize=(16, 10),) 
plt.axhline(y=40, color='r', linestyle='-')
plt.axhline(y=25, color='b', linestyle='-')
plt.show()
```

The graph looks like this:

[image]

I would like to fill in colour for area where temperature is **between 25°C and 40°C(inside the triangle)**. Can I do this by tweaking my code? If not, what's a good way of doing this? Thanks!

Note: The data is not continuous, but has been forward filled to have constant interval of 1 second. Also, temperature at the peak is above 40°C and the corresponding vertical section in `Timestamp` should not be coloured.

Comment: If you could post your whole dataset that would help people provide a complete example :)

Comment: Hi @CDJB thanks for the comment but I'm afraid the complete dataset would be too large to post here..

Comment: How is this related with plotly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can suggest this approach using `fill_between` using the `where` argument:

```
Timestamp = pd.date_range('2020-02-06 08:23:04', periods=1000, freq='s')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp': Timestamp,
                   'Temperature': 30+15*np.cos(np.linspace(0,10,Timestamp.size))})

df['top_lim'] = 40.
df['bottom_lim'] = 25.

plt.plot_date(df['Timestamp'], df['Temperature'], '-')
plt.plot_date(df['Timestamp'], df['top_lim'], '-', color='r')
plt.plot_date(df['Timestamp'], df['bottom_lim'], '-', color='blue')

plt.fill_between(df['Timestamp'], df['bottom_lim'], df['Temperature'],
                where=(df['Temperature'] >= df['bottom_lim'])&(df['Temperature'] <= df['top_lim']),
                facecolor='orange', alpha=0.3)

########### EDIT ################

# plt.fill_between(df['Timestamp'], df['bottom_lim'], df['top_lim'],
#                 where=(df['Temperature'] >= df['top_lim']),
#                 facecolor='orange', alpha=0.3)


mask = (df['Temperature'] <= df['top_lim'])&(df['Temperature'] >= df['bottom_lim'])
plt.scatter(df['Timestamp'][mask], df['Temperature'][mask], marker='.', color='black')
cumulated_time = df['Timestamp'][mask].diff().sum()
plt.title(f'Cumulated time in range = {cumulated_time}')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Andrea, thanks for the solution. Would it be possible to exclude the portion where the curve exceeds 40? Because I want to calculate the accumulated time where temperature is between 25 and 40

Comment: I'm not sure I got what you are asking. Does the edit answer your question?

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I want! Just one question, is there a way to replace `.diff`? As column `Timestamp ` is `index` format, it returned `AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'diff'`

Comment: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49277932/difference-pandas-datetimeindex-without-a-frequency) the answer :)