# Calculate Pandas df timedelta of index

Tags: python, pandas

Would anyone know how to calculate the time delta of the time stamp of the index?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# simulate some data
# ===================================
np.random.seed(0)
dt_rng = pd.date_range('2015-03-02 00:00:00', '2015-07-19 23:00:00', freq='T')
dt_idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(np.random.choice(dt_rng, size=2000, replace=False))
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2000), index=dt_idx, columns=['col']).sort_index()

df
```

Am I on track using `df['elapsed_time'] = pd.TimedeltaIndex(df)` at all [with this](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.TimedeltaIndex.html)?

This will throw an error:
`ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2000, placement implies 1`

Comment: You can't pass a DataFrame. Only a Series. `df['elapsed_time'] = pd.TimedeltaIndex(df.index)`

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're trying to do though because this will just take the underlying ns datetime and _force_ it into a time delta. It won't do any timedelta comparison.

Comment: It seems like you're likely looking for `df['elapsed_time'] = df.index.to_series().diff()` [Difference pandas.DateTimeIndex without a frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49277932/15497888)

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31551099/pandas-difference-in-index-with-date-values#:%7E:text=elegant%20way%20to%20convert%20to%20float%20is) is beautiful!

This will create another pandas column which I called `time_td` where then I can cast it as a `timedelta64` where `m` stands for minutes which I am looking for.

```
df['time_td'] = df.index.to_series().diff().astype('timedelta64[m]')
```

I can then sum this `time_td` column with:

`df.time_td.sum()`